# Constraints making UITextView smaller

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I just put constraints into my ViewController, and I set the UITextView so that it keeps its height and width, yet at runtime it shrinks to only cover the text inside of it. How can I avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the same, or are you adding the UITextView at run time?

Comment: the text view is not added at run time, but it is just an ordinary text view that gets its text at run time and shrinks to fit the text when constraints are set (which I do not want to happen)  @gurmandeep

Comment: @gurmandeep I think the size is changing because the text is being added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, at the run time, the size of your TextView has changed because of the content, I mean the text set to it. To prevent this kind of issue, I would suggest some options which will be regarding your UI

At first, if you intend to fix size of the TextView, so from the constraints or Interface Builder, please create width and height constraints then fix the value. For example
[image]

If you wish your text view will be dynamically in size based on contents, you can set width and height values are greater than or equal a minimum value as it will not break your UI

[image]

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: this is great advice! I tried this and it fixed my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Interface Builder.   Check the value for Content Hugging Priority that IB set for the text view.   If it's too high, it may be overriding your constraints.

Comment: I checked that but that was not the issue, ty tho